# Sharepoint API URL Confusion

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload a file to the SharePoint API. I'm following this webpage: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_createuploadsession

What I'm confused on is the endpoint you're supposed to make the POST request to has an itemId. An example being 'POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession'. What is the item I'm supposed to have an ID for? It's as if I'm supposed to create a mock file beforehand - but that's exactly what this endpoint is for.

Where do I get this ItemId?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research looking at examples and found out that the 'itemId' that I was looking for was a 'drive' id, then I needed to add the new filename to the end of the url. My finished endpoint looked like this: `groups/{group.Id}/drive/items/{drive.Id}:/{file.Name}:/createUploadSession`